# Inserting UNICODE into Oracle from C/C++ shows garbage in DB

Tags: c++, oracle, unicode, oracle-pro-c

I have the below sample program...

```
int main(void)
{
    char insertQuery[] = "INSERT INTO ABCD_TABLE VALUES('987','31-AUG-16','19-JAN-17','901',
'31-DEC-12','1',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'ÜÜcreate02_de,ää\')";
    connectToSQLServer();
    executeINSERTQuery(insertQuery);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, the query is inserted successfully into the DB but the `ÜÜ` is shown as garbage.

When I run the same query manually in `Toad`, it is inserted proprly and the `ÜÜ` is shown properly in `Toda`.

```
"INSERT INTO ABCD_TABLE VALUES('987','31-AUG-16','19-JAN-17','901','31-DEC-12','1','','','','','','','ÜÜcreate02_de,ää')";
```

What might be the issue?
Please do let me know if you guys need the code sample of `connectToSQLServer()` and `executeINSERTQuery(insertQuery)`. I will provide.

Answer (score 0):

You have set NLS_LANG variable to ALL32UTF8. Also there is a way how to do it on OCI level, see: OCIEnvNlsCreate and [Database Globalization Support Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch10oci.htm).

By doing this you till tell the OCI driver that everything you store in buffers is in UTF8 charset, and everything withdrawn from from database also must be in UTF8.

PS: note that some OCI api functions do distinguish number of bytes and number of characters. So for example you must not use OCILobRead/OCILobWrite to manipulate CLOBS. You must use extended versions OCILobRead2/OCILobWrite2.